# Replacing duplicates instead of deleting them

Tags: list-manipulation

My code replaces each repeated element by "X".

```
ReplaceRepeated[{1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 
    7}, {a1___, y_ /; y != #, a2___, y_, a3___} :> {a1, y, a2, #, 
     a3}] &@"X"

(*{1, 2, 3, "X", 5, "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 7}*)
```

What is the most elegant code to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
ClearAll[replaceDuplicates]
replaceDuplicates[rep_: "X"] := Module[{f}, f[y_] := (f[y] = rep; y); f /@ #] &
```

***Examples:***

```
replaceDuplicates[] @ {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 7}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, "X", 5, "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 7}
> ```

```
replaceDuplicates[Nothing] @ {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 7}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 5, 7}
> ```

Alternatively:

```
ClearAll[replaceDuplicates2]
replaceDuplicates2[rep_: "X"] := Module[{y = #}, 
   y[[Join @@ (Rest /@ Values @ PositionIndex[y])]] = rep; y] &
```

***Examples:***

```
replaceDuplicates2[] @ {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 7}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, "X", 5, "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 7}
> ```

```
replaceDuplicates2[Nothing] @ {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 7}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 5, 7}
> ```

Comment: Very clever, and ten times faster than what I suggested. Cheers!

Comment: I am trying to understand what your function is really doing.

Comment: @azerbajdzan the heart of it is this definition `f[y_] := (f[y] = rep; y)` which will execute the first time it sees a value `y` and first perform the assignment `f[y] = rep` and then return `y`. That is why the values do not get replaced with `"X"` the first time they are seen. On the next time the value `y` is seen, because of the assignment `f[y] = rep`, the function simply returns `y`. All of this is wrapped in `Module` so it's cleaned up properly and then the function is mapped over the list of arguments.

Comment: Thank you @Roman.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, as b3m2a1 explains, this is a memoization trick ([tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)): The function `f`  returns `a`  first time it encounters `a` and  _redefines_ itself to return `"X"` next time it encounters `a`.

Comment: +1. One nitpick is that one would need to call `Clear[f]`  (but not `ClearAll`!) at the end before returning the result, otherwise `f` will not be garbage-collected and will hang around indefinitely after the call to `replaceDuplicates` - and if you call it multiple times, then just as many different `f`s will be left hanging around.

Comment: Thank you @Leonid. Excellent point.

Answer (score 12):

```
FoldPairList[If[MemberQ[#1, #2], {"X", #1}, {#2, Append[##]}] &,
             {},
             {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 7}]

(*    {1, 2, 3, "X", 5, "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 7}    *)
```

[`FoldPairList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) accumulates a list of "already seen" numbers, starting with the empty list. If the new number is in the "already seen" list, we emit "X" and keep the list unchanged; otherwise, we emit the new number and add it to the "already seen" list (with `Append[##]` being an abbreviation for `Append[#1, #2]`).

Answer (score 10):

You may use [`PositionIndex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) with [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html).

With

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 7};
```

and

```
replaceDups[expr_, rep_ : "X"] := 
 ReplacePart[expr, List /@ Flatten[Rest /@ Values@PositionIndex@expr] -> rep]
```

Then

```
replaceDups[x]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, "X", 5, "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 7}
> ```

Is also faster than OP solution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Not that elegant but rather straight.

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 7}

ReplacePart[A, {#} & /@ 
   Select[Range[Length[A]], MemberQ[Take[A, # - 1], A[[#]]] &] -> "X"]
```

Note that

```
Select[Range[Length[A]], MemberQ[Take[A, # - 1], A[[#]]] &]
```

is a set of indices those are duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 7};
```

Positions of duplicates

```
p = Splice @* Rest /@ Values @ PositionIndex[list]
```

{7, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 8, 9}

Using `SubsetMap` to replace

```
SubsetMap[Array["X"&,Length @ p]&, list, p]
```

{1, 2, 3, "X", 5, "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 7}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 7};
```

---

Using `MapAt`:

```
p = Outer[List, Catenate[Rest /@ Values@PositionIndex[list]]]

(*{{7}, {4}, {6}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {8}, {9}}*)

MapAt["X" &, list, p]

(*{1, 2, 3, "X", 5, "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 7}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative relying on `Ordering` :

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 7};

Permute[
  KeyValueMap[Splice@ArrayPad[{#1}, {0, #2 - 1}, "X"] &]@KeySort@Counts@#
  , Ordering@#] &@list
```

> `{1, 2, 3, "X", 5, "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 7}`